# using on to grab a generated date and reuse it jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, momentjs

There is a list of dates generated by a jquery plugin. I can do this with moment.js and it works:

See this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/UJ9z4/).

When I try to apply it to the live file with the plugin running, I get an undefined error.

I understand this to mean, that I cant grab the date because it was newly created in the DOM. So, I am trying to use "on" to grab the contents of the span after it loads, but its not working. I have tried it different ways looking at different threads and none seem to work.

this is the code

```
    <!--template for calendar list -->      
    <div id="cactuscal">
   <div class="gcf-item-container-block">
  <div class="gcf-item-block">
    <div class="gcf-item-header-block">
      <div class="gcf-item-date-block">
        <span class="gcf-item-daterange"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="gcf-item-title-block">
        <strong class="gcf-item-title"></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gcf-item-body-block">
      <div class="gcf-item-description">
      </div>
      <div class="gcf-item-location">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div><!--template for calendar list -->        
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $('#cactuscal').gCalFlow({
        calid: 'myaddress@gmail.com',
        link_item_title: false,
         maxitem: 6,
    daterange_formatter: function(sd, ed, allday_p) { return "<span class='startdate' data-date='" + (sd.getFullYear()) + "-" + (sd.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (sd.getDate()) +"'>" + "</span>" + " – " + "<span id='enddate'"+">" + (ed.getFullYear()) + "-" + (ed.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (ed.getDate()) + "</span>" }
      });

    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("ready",function(){
    $('.startdate').each(function () {
    var then = $(this);

date = moment(then.attr('data-date')),
update = function(){
    then.html(date.format("dddd[(]M[/]D[)]"));
    then.trigger('onCreated');
};

update();
setInterval(update, 60000);
});
    });
</script>
```

there is no option in the gcalflow to format a date range the way i want so i thought to use moment to grab the string and reformat it that way.

do i need to create a new option in the gcalpro script to format the way i want? or will this work?
the html part is the template for the google calendar feed. the first js is the call to gcalflow to display the calendar feed. the last js is to reformat the formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

The gCalFlow call works asynchronously, so your code for updating the elements gets called before the DOM elements from the gCalFlow are created. (You can not know precisely when gCalFlow creates the elements)

What you should do instead is to add your code as a callback function in the cCalFlow call. This way it gets called *after* cCalFlow is finished.

```
$('#cactuscal').gCalFlow({
    calid: 'myaddress@gmail.com',
    link_item_title: false,
    maxitem: 6,
    daterange_formatter: function(sd, ed, allday_p) {
        return "<span class='startdate' data-date='" + (sd.getFullYear()) + "-" + (sd.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (sd.getDate()) + "'>" + "</span>" + " – " + "<span id='enddate'" + ">" + (ed.getFullYear()) + "-" + (ed.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (ed.getDate()) + "</span>"
    },
    callback: afterGCalFlowIsFinished
});

function afterGCalFlowIsFinished(){
    $('.startdate').each(function() {
        ...
    }
}
```